# Higher the percentage, lower the value

Tags: percentages

I need to work out a grading based on a percentage. The higher the percentage, the lower the grading. There are 7 major grades in the score, 1 to 7

(100% = 1) & 
(0% = 7)

I need to work out the score value based on the % value. Is there a way to do this? For example: what score between 1 & 7 would 68% be? the 1 to 7 values need to be be point values i.e. 3.87

I cant seem to get the right method

Thanks

Nacho

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want a linear transformation (and it does not need to be linear), and the [two point form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_equation#Two-point_form) is what you need.  You have two points: $(100,1)$ and $(0,7)$ The line through them (taking subscript $1$ to be the second point) is $y-7=\frac {7-1}{0-100}x$ or $y=7-\frac 6{100}x$